# How to find the cause of an unresponsive ui in a javafx application

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx application deployed as a desktop application and the ui becomes unresponsive after its being running for 2 to 3 days. The application is running 24 hours per day. There are no exceptions in logs and it hangs at different points, what are common  causes of this and how could I find the problem?

Comment: It's hard to say without further information, but the most common problem when dealing with unresponsive UIs is the  thread becoming locked. In this situation, there are usually other tasks that are running on the main thread that can block (take over) when waiting for a task to complete, most commonly present in networked applications.

Comment: Are there any logs produced by the jvm that could help?

Comment: You can profile your app with [Java VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html), it is included in JDK.