# JAVAFX application UI become unresponsive

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have an desktop application based on javafx.The only requirement is that it has to run continuously for 5-6 days.I am in testing phase.

### UI component used in this:

- 6 Gauges (Medusa)
- Line chart that is stacked on JFXDrawer and is controlled by a hamburger-button.

Out of 6 gauges 3 gauges and line chart has to be updated on a period of a sec. For this i have used a thread which update this component per second.

I have tested this application for almost 3 time:

1. For Three days
2. For 26 hours(In which graph is working fine and values are updating in the gauges but the gauge needle is stuck at a particular value)
3. For 24 hours now the gauge needle is moving but gauge value is stuck and the Line chart drawer is not open only the hamburger-icon is changing.

There is no Exception in log and the UI is not hanging, Just Ui components are not responsive.

I did profiling but everything seems OK.I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492349/how-to-find-the-cause-of-an-unresponsive-ui-in-a-javafx-application) also but in his case the ui is hanging and i have no issue regarding this, all the button are clicky and i am able to change the screens with not issue.

After reloading the Screen All gets back to normal.

sample code i've used to update the component.

> Controller

```
public class testGaugeController implements Initializable {

// Component
private static final int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 1000;
private int xSeriesData = 0;
private final XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
private ExecutorService executor;
private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ1 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
private NumberAxis xAxis,yAxis;
LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart;
DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler();
Connection connect = dh.MakeConnection();
@FXML
private JFXDrawer drawer;
@FXML
private JFXHamburger burger;
@FXML
private Gauge Gauge;


/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 *
 * @param url
 * @param rb
 */
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) throws IOException {
    initializeRecorder();
    start_recording();
}

private void initializeRecorder() throws IOException {
    try {
        xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, MAX_DATA_POINTS, MAX_DATA_POINTS / 100);
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
        xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(true);
        xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(true);
        xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(true);
        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        // Create a LineChart
        lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis) {
            // Override to remove symbols on each data point
            @Override
            protected void dataItemAdded(XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series, int itemIndex, XYChart.Data<Number, Number> item) {
            }
        };

        lineChart.setAnimated(false);
        lineChart.setTitle("");
        lineChart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(true);

        series1.setName("Test Value");
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);

        drawer.setSidePane(lineChart);
        drawer.setOverLayVisible(false);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition burgermove = new HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition(burger);
    burgermove.setRate(-1);
    burger.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (evt) -> {
        burgermove.setRate(burgermove.getRate() * -1);
        burgermove.play();
        if (drawer.isShown()) {
            drawer.close();
        } else {
            drawer.open();
        }

    });
}

int count_executer_status = 0;
boolean initial_start_trend = true;
private void start_recording() {
    if (initial_start_trend) {
        initial_start_trend = false;
    } else {
        xSeriesData = 0;
        System.out.println("Clearing dataQue");
        dataQ1.clear();
        series1.getData().clear();
    }

    xAxis.setLowerBound(0);
    count_executer_status++;
    System.out.println("Cleared dataQue");
    executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool((Runnable r) -> {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        return thread;
    });
    count_executer_status = 0;
    AddToQueue addToQueue = new AddToQueue();
    executor.execute(addToQueue);
    //-- Prepare Timeline
    prepareTimeline();
}

private class AddToQueue implements Runnable {

    String query = "SELECT test_value FROM test_data_reader ORDER BY test_data_reader_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    ResultSet rs;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // add a item of random data to queue.
            rs = dh.getData(query, connect);
            if (rs.next()) {
                double test_value = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("test_value"));
                dataQ1.add(test_value);
                String Record_data = "INSERT INTO `test_data_record` (`test_value`, `date_time`) VALUES( '" + rs.getString("test_value") + "', NOW());";
                dh.execute(Record_data, connect);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    Gauge.setValue(test_value);
                });

            }
            xaxis_count++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            executor.execute(this);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}}

//-- Timeline gets called in the JavaFX Main thread
private void prepareTimeline() {
    // Every frame to take any data from queue and add to chart
    new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            addDataToSeries();
        }
    }.start();
}
int xaxis_count = 0;

private void addDataToSeries() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            //-- add 20 numbers to the plot+
            if (dataQ1.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(xaxis_count, dataQ1.remove()));
        }

        if (series1.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
            series1.getData().remove(0, series1.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        }
        // update
        xAxis.setLowerBound(xSeriesData - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(xSeriesData - 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDrawer?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger?>
<?import eu.hansolo.medusa.Gauge?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="e913_300mt.testGaugeController">
   <children>
    <VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <children>
            <HBox fx:id="sectionHeader" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2F333E;">
            <children>
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <children>
                        <JFXHamburger fx:id="burger" />
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <children>
                <Gauge fx:id="gauge" autoScale="false" borderPaint="#0099ff" borderWidth="3.0" decimals="0" foregroundPaint="#0000000b" highlightSections="true" innerShadowEnabled="true" knobType="METAL" lcdDesign="RED" lcdFont="LCD" majorTickMarkType="PILL" majorTickSpace="250.0" markersVisible="true" maxValue="3000.0" mediumTickMarkType="TRAPEZOID" mediumTickMarksVisible="false" minorTickSpace="50.0" needleSize="THIN" needleType="VARIOMETER" shadowsEnabled="true" threshold="300.0" title="Test Gauge" unit="unit" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </Gauge>
            </children>
            </HBox>
        </children>
    </VBox>
    <JFXDrawer fx:id="drawer" defaultDrawerSize="600.0" direction="RIGHT" layoutY="56.0" prefHeight="344.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Libraries

1. jfoenix-8.0.1-for-java8.jar  [Github](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix)
2. fontawesomefx-8.9.jar  [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx/downloads/)
3. Medusa-8.0.jar  [jar-download](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/eu.hansolo/Medusa/8.0/source-code)

For testing purpose i am only updating one gauge.And system Configuration is :

1. OS : Ubuntu 18.04 lts
2. Processor : Intel core i5-8400
3. Ram : 8Gb

Any Idea on this.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? Also - any system information (hardware, OS version etc.)

Comment: There's one thing that is not properly synchronized: `xaxis_count` is accessed from both the JavaFX application thread and the executor. Since it's not `volatile` and not accessed while synchronizing to the same lock, at some time the JVM will probably keep one copies of the variable, 1 for each thread and the application thread won't see updates done to the var from the background thread. Furthermore I'm not sure why you're using `ExecutorService`+`Thread.sleep` for repeatedly executing a task. `ScheduledExecutorService` is designed to handle this for you!

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (haven't you been advised to do so in an earlier question ... *wondering)

Comment: Also the code is not a [mcve]: while minimal is arguable, its neither "complete" (missing fxml at least if you opt for the fxml injection instead of a plain java example) nor "verifiable" (using custom classes that nobody except you can see - those probably are not the reason for you problem but prevents us to throw your example into our IDEs and run )

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake, I've updated this issue with complete code

Comment: okay .. but why do you still not comply ;)